# how to get Difference between Two Dates in Javascript Year/Month/Day

Tags: javascript

I need the difference between two dates in javascript,  this is my date format 24-05-2018, and I need no of year, no of months, no of days

Comment: use momentjs for that.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/5995973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date1 = new Date(date1.getUTCFullYear(), date1.getUTCMonth(), date1.getUTCDate(), date1.getUTCHours(), date1.getUTCMinutes(), date1.getUTCSeconds());
date2 = new Date(date2.getUTCFullYear(), date2.getUTCMonth(), date2.getUTCDate(), date2.getUTCHours(), date2.getUTCMinutes(), date2.getUTCSeconds());

let diff_ms = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
let diff = Math.round(diff_ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

This will give you difference in no of days. You can then deduce year, month, days.

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It is much easy with this.

```
var date1 = moment('24-05-2018','DD-MM-YYYY');
var date2   = moment('24-05-2019','DD-MM-YYYY');

var years = date2.diff(date1, 'year');
date1.add(years, 'years');

var months = date2.diff(date1, 'months');
date1.add(months, 'months');

var days = date2.diff(date1, 'days');
```