# How to get day difference between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, days

Say I have two dates: `1/24/2020 11:55:00 PM` and `1/25/2020 01:00:00 AM`. Real difference between them is about `2 hours` but the day has changed. I want the difference in days which would be `1`.

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054494/6288172 but it doesn't give me the right answer.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: You can have the answer herer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @FábioBCSouza it doesn't work. A difference of 2 hours would give me day difference smaller than 0.5 which would mean same day. But in my example above, even though its only 2 hours but the day has changed so the answer should be 1.

Comment: Since you're interested in only days, you can set both dates to the same hour, minutes and seconds and use that solution.

Comment: @Titus That seems like a good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
// your code goes here
var time = new Date(2020,0,25,23,23,23,2);
var date = new Date(time.toDateString()); // Sat Jan 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

var time1 = new Date(2020,0,26,2,2,2,2);
var date1 = new Date(time1.toDateString()); // Sun Jan 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

var diff = Math.round(Math.abs((date - date1)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

console.log(diff); //1
```